# Bind9 stops responding to queries every now and then

Tags: bind, bind9

I am setting up a bind9 service and I am monitoring it with zabbix. I see that zabbix builds me such posts as in the picture. This actually translates to my query. What could be wrong, have any of you encountered such a problem?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to look into your verbose BIND logs (enable them, first), to figure out whether it's likely to be a problem on BIND's end. You'll also want to look at the operating system (which one? Linux?) kernel logs, to rule out networking interruptions.